# JSR 352 - dynamic job loading

Tags: java, batch-file

The spec in chapter 10.6 says:

> Implementation-specific loader
>
> The batch runtime implementation must provide an implementation-specific means by which Job XML references are resolved to a Job XML document.
>
> The purpose of an implementation-specific loader is to enable Job XML loading from outside of the application archive, such as from a repository, file system, remote cache, or elsewhere.

I wondered where to find the documentation about the IBM reference impl. specific job loading?

I want to to add new job definitions at runtime. The the directory containing job definition files seems to loaded once.

Comment: Are you using the default DelegatingJobXMLLoaderServiceImpl in the reference implementation? If so, that uses META-INF/batch-jobs to load the job definitions. That directory would most likely be contained in your jar file and typically is not able to be written to.

Answer (score 2):

For the RI in Glassfish, we provided an implementation-specific means mostly as a formality (and I'm not sure if/where it's even documented).

The mechanism is to load from a
JobOperator.start(JOB_NAME,...)
from:
    **$JSL_DIR**/*JOB_NAME*.xml

If anyone is still interested, I can complete this answer with the rest of the instructions to make this work.